# Xamarin.Forms: WebView support on Android 5.1

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop, android-min-sdk

I've developed a **Xamarin.Forms.Shell app** where I use a `WebView` to manage appointments.

By default, I let the `Android minimum Version` to **5.0**, as I still have an old device on Android 5.1 that I use for tests.

I can **deploy** the app on my device through **Visual Studio**, but the app is **no launched automatically**. I can **launch the app handly**, but the app **crashes** just after the splashscreen has been displayed, and I don't see any traces on **AppCenter**, whereas **Diagnostics** and **Analytics** are well activated.

In the same time, I can **install the app** through **AppCenter Distribution**: in this case, I can launch and use the app. But  when I open the page containing the `WebView`: nothing happens, I get an empty page...

As I can't debug this, I would like to know if there is an explanation related to the `WebView` and **Android version 5.x**? As this version is no very longer present on the market, I will probably update `Android minimum Version` to 6.0.

Comment: Android’s native web browser is called WebKit. Each version of Android has a different WebKit version and starting from 5.0+, the WebKit was separated from the SDK and hence could be updated separately by the OS. This can lead to an enormous array of possible configurations for the WebView on Android. In earlier versions of Android, it used the standard OS browser rendering engine, called WebKit, not to be confused with the Android control called WebKit. As of 4.4, this changed to Chromium based, however its not identical to the Chrome Browser App.

Comment: So in my case, and taken into consideration the part of the Android 5.x market, it's preferable to remove the support of Android 5.x in my app, no? Instead of spending some time to make it work without access to the Debug...